# Spring Data Jpa 3.0.0 error with YesNoConverter and JpaRepository-query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using the hibernate YesNoConverter to store booleans as 'Y'/'N' in my database.
Currently I'm migrating to Spring Boot 3.0 (with spring-data-jpa:3.0.0) and the custom JpaRepository-query "findByActiveFalse" crashes.

```
List<ExampleEntity> findByActiveFalse();
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select e1_0.id,e1_0.active from example_entity e1_0 where e1_0.active=0]; SQL [n/a]
```

The Hibernate YesNoConverter doesn't get triggered and so there is a Zero instead of 'N'. (Before upgrading to Spring Boot 3.0 I had an own implementation of this Converter which has the same problems)

With "findByActive(false)" the query is working without problems.

Here are my sources:

JpaRepository: https://github.com/GuybrushDevwood/boolean-converter-demo/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/booleanconverterdemo/example/ExampleEntityRepo.java

Entity: https://github.com/GuybrushDevwood/boolean-converter-demo/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/booleanconverterdemo/example/ExampleEntity.java

Testcase: https://github.com/GuybrushDevwood/boolean-converter-demo/blob/main/src/test/java/com/example/booleanconverterdemo/example/ExampleEntityRepoTest.java

Do I have to configure anything to get this working as before?

Comment: I am running into the same issue with spring data 3.0.1, did you find any resolution?

Comment: Instead of findByActiveFalse() you can create a query findByActive(boolean b) and you can call it with findByActive(false).

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to refactor your code, this is a nice temporary solution.

```
public interface ExampleRepository extends JpaRepository<ExampleEntity, String> {
    List<ExampleEntity> findByActive(boolean active);

    default List<ExampleEntity> findByActiveFalse(){
        return findByActive(false);
    }
}
```

Alternative:

```
@Query("select e FROM exampleentity where e.active= true");
```

Using the criteriabuilder:

```
builder.equals(root.get("repeat), true);
```